# How get slideIndex back to slideIndex

Tags: javascript, arrays, slider, undefined

I am trying to understand why this code isn't going back to slideIndex = 0;

Can someone please explain, at the forth click I am getting undefined instead of jumping back to the first index of the slide?

Thank you for explaining.

```
slideIndex = 0;

    function nextSlide() {

        console.log(slides[slideIndex]);   
               

       slideIndex++;

       if(slideIndex > slides.length){
        slideIndex = 0;
        }
      
    }
```

---

Actually this the whole code, so I am trying to understand why the slideIndex is not jumping back to slideIndex=0;
One the `slideIndex > myArray.length;` it needs to jump back to the initializes slideIndex, but I am getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at HTMLButtonElement.

Please help:

```
slideIndex=0;

const prevbtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextbtn = document.querySelector(".next");

let myArray = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let i = 0;


for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block";


  nextbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    myArray[slideIndex+1].style.display="block";
    
   slideIndex++;

   if(slideIndex >= myArray.length-1){
    console.log("yes");
slideIndex=0;
}
});

prevbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(this answer refers to code supplied by the author within another answer)

the problem is this line: `myArray[slideIndex+1].style.display="block";`

let's say there are 9 items in `myArray` and `slideIndex` is 8. then the above tries to set the style on `myArray[9]` which does not exist.

you can fix this by either moving the style change to after you've adjusted and validated the `slideIndex` (in your next two lines), or you can use a modulus adjustment such as this: `myArray[(slideIndex+1)%myArray.length].style.display="block";`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering, but I am using this: `myArray[slideIndex+1].style.display="block";` for jumping by first click to next image otherwise you have to click twice before going to next image.

I have now this code which seems to work except that I have to click twice when page load to get the next image.
How can that be fixed?

```
let slideIndex=0;

const prevbtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextbtn = document.querySelector(".next");

let myArray = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].style.display = "none";
}

myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block";

nextbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(slideIndex > myArray.length-1){
        slideIndex = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
             myArray[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block";       
    }

    myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    console.log(slideIndex);

    slideIndex++; 

});

prevbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working, but I am not sure if this a good written code, except that I can simplify the code.

```
let slideIndex=0;

const prevbtn = document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextbtn = document.querySelector(".next");

let myArray = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].style.display = "none";
    }

myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block";

nextbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(slideIndex == 0){
        slideIndex = slideIndex + 1;
    }

    if(slideIndex > myArray.length-1){
        slideIndex = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                 myArray[i].style.display = "none";
                }

        myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block"; 

    }

    if(slideIndex<myArray.length){
        
       myArray[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
       console.log(slideIndex);
    }
        slideIndex++; 
});

prevbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
});
```